# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, collection

I am trying to filter the data from my custom table, But it is throwing Error.

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class
>   Test\Learning\ResourceModel\Learning\Collection
>   in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\app\code\Test\Learning\Model\ResourceModel\Learning\Collection.php
>   on line 24

**Block/Learning.php**

```
<?php
namespace Test\Learning\Block;


class Learning extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{


    /**
     * @var \Test\Learning\Model\LearningFactory
     */
    protected  $_learningFactory;


    public function __construct
    (
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Test\Learning\Model\LearningFactory $learningFactory,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_learningFactory = $learningFactory;

    }

    public function getFilterData(){


        $customerId = "1";
        $data = $this->_learningFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter(array('customer_id',$customerId));

        foreach ($data as $k => $v) {

        }       

        return $data;
    }

}
```

**Model/Learning/ResourceModel/Learning/Collection.php**

```
<?php
namespace Test\Learning\ResourceModel\Learning;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_idFieldName = 'clul_id';

    /**
     * Define resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Test\Learning\Model\Learning', 'Test\Learning\Model\ResourceModel\Learning');
        $this->_map['fields']['clul_id'] = 'main_table.clul_id';
    }


}
```

**/view/frontend/templates/learning.phtml**

```
<?php echo $block->getFilterData(); ?>
```

Any help On this?

Comment: Namespace is incorrect use `Test\Learning\Model\ResourceModel\Learning` instead `Test\Learning\ResourceModel\Learning` in Collection..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your collection class needs to be in the file `Test/Learning/Model/ResourceModel/Learning/Collection.php` and have the namespace `namespace Test\Learning\Model\ResourceModel\Learning;`

Comment: i think it ok? why you used "\" before at class Collection?

Comment: Sorry for the extra backslash.

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep below line in your function,

```
$data = $this->_learningFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', array('eq' => $customerId));
```